# Expressions in media queries in mixins

Tags: less

I've got a mixin like so:

```
   .media-query (@n) {
        @media all and (max-width: (@n + 1) * (@video-box-width + 2) + (@n+2) * @video-box-margin + (@sidebar-width + 20px) + @margins * 2){
            #container_inner {
                width: @n * (@video-box-width + 2) + (@n+1) * @video-box-margin + (@sidebar-width + 20px);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I get a parse error because of the exression after max-width. It works when only one variable is after, like max-width: @variable. I tried setting a variable at the top of the mixin, but because variables are actually constants, it won't change with different values of @n.

Edit:
I want to call it multiple times like so

```
.media-query(3);
.media-query(2);
.media-query(1);
```

With this, I get a layout that resizes with the browser, but only takes on certain set of predefined widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit, March 13**: LESS Version 1.3 is now available and solves this problem, see the [changelog](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG). Try again and be surprised :)

**Edit, March 2**: Didn't get the question right, actual answer should be:

That's a known bug, and there are already [several](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/654) [open](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/544) [issues](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/122) over at GitHub indicating that LESS currently offers only limited support for `@media` queries. Sorry, we'll have to wait until that get's fixed or come up with a clever workaround :-∫

Comment: The problem with that is, once @max-width is defined with one value of @n, it can't be redefined (since variables in less are actually constants). See my above edits. And it will give me a responsive layout, again see above.

Comment: Sorry, I get it now. Edited the answer, bottom line is: that's a known bug.